# Magento unable to access block class function from another phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have a Block class under the path, which im trying to access a function `getPosts()`

**UPDATED:**

**app\code\community\Fishpig\Wordpress\Block\Post\List.php**

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->_getPostCollection();
}

protected function _getPostCollection()
{
$artical_type = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('article_type');
    if (is_null($this->_postCollection) && $this->getWrapperBlock()) {
        $this->_postCollection = $this->getWrapperBlock()->getPostCollection();
        
        if ($this->_postCollection) {
            if ($this->getPostType()) {
                $this->_postCollection->addPostTypeFilter($this->getPostType());
                if(!empty($artical_type)) {
                    $posttypevalue = Mage::helper('wordpress')->getPostMetaData();
                    if(!empty($posttypevalue)) {
                        $this->_postCollection = $this->_postCollection->addFieldToFilter('ID',array('in' => $posttypevalue));
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if ($this->getPagerBlock()) {
                $this->getPagerBlock()->setCollection($this->_postCollection);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $this->_postCollection;
}

/**
 * Sets the parent block of this block
 * This block can be used to auto generate the post list
 *
 * @param Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List_Wrapper_Abstract $wrapper
 * @return $this
 */
public function setWrapperBlock(Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List_Wrapper_Abstract $wrapper)
{
    return $this->setData('wrapper_block', $wrapper);
}

/**
 * Get the pager block
 * If the block isn't set in the layout XML, it will be created and will use the default template
 *
 * @return Fishpig_Wordpress_Post_List_Pager
 */
public function getPagerBlock()
{
    if (!$this->hasPagerBlock()) {
        $this->setPagerBlock(false);
        
        if (!$this->getChild('pager')) {
            $this->setChild('pager', $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('wordpress/post_list_pager')
                    ->setNameInLayout('wordpress_post_list')
                    ->setAlias('pager')
            );
        }

        if ($pager = $this->getChild('pager')) {
            $this->setPagerBlock(
                $pager->setPostListBlock($this)
            );
        }
    }
    
    return $this->_getData('pager_block');
}
```

In its respective phtml file, it has:

**app\design\frontend\rau\default\template\wordpress\post\list.phtml**

```
<?php $posts = $this->getPosts() ?>
```

If i do `count($posts);` in this `list.phtml` i get the count value.

But the same Block im trying to access in another phtml file like:

**app\design\frontend\rau\default\template\wordpress\common.phtml**

**UPDATE:**

```
$searchcountobj = new Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List();   print_r($searchcountobj);
$searchcount = $searchcountobj->getPosts();  echo 'COUNT:'.count($searchcount);
```

Output of `get_class_methods($searchcountobj)`

> Array ( [0] => getPosts [1] => _getPostCollection [2] => setWrapperBlock [3] => getPagerBlock [4] => getPagerHtml [5] => getPostRenderer [6] => getPostRendererTemplate [7] => _prepareLayout [8] => _beforeToHtml [9] => getPost [10] => getPage [11] => getPostId [12] => canComment [13] => canDisplayPreviousNextLinks [14] => getPasswordProtectHtml [15] => displayExcerptInFeed [16] => preparePost [17] => _getBlockForPostPrepare [18] => getAfterPostContentHtml [19] => getBeforePostContentHtml [20] => _getChildTextList [21] => getMetaBlock [22] => escapeHtml [23] => _construct [24] => getTemplate [25] => setTemplate [26] => getTemplateFile [27] => getArea [28] => assign [29] => setScriptPath [30] => getDirectOutput [31] => getShowTemplateHints [32] => fetchView [33] => renderView [34] => _toHtml [35] => getBaseUrl [36] => getJsUrl [37] => getObjectData [38] => getCacheKeyInfo [39] => _getAllowSymlinks [40] => __construct [41] => _getFactory [42] => _getApp [43] => getRequest [44] => getParentBlock [45] => setParentBlock [46] => getAction [47] => setLayout [48] => getLayout [49] => getIsAnonymous [50] => setIsAnonymous [51] => getAnonSuffix [52] => setAnonSuffix [53] => getBlockAlias [54] => setBlockAlias [55] => setNameInLayout [56] => getSortedChildren [57] => setAttribute [58] => setChild [59] => unsetChild [60] => unsetCallChild [61] => unsetChildren [62] => getChild [63] => getChildHtml [64] => getChildChildHtml [65] => getSortedChildBlocks [66] => _getChildHtml [67] => _beforeChildToHtml [68] => getBlockHtml [69] => insert [70] => sortChildren [71] => append [72] => addToChildGroup [73] => addToParentGroup [74] => getChildGroup [75] => getChildData [76] => setFrameTags [77] => toHtml [78] => _afterToHtml [79] => _getUrlModelClass [80] => _getUrlModel [81] => getUrl [82] => getUrlBase64 [83] => getUrlEncoded [84] => getSkinUrl [85] => getMessagesBlock [86] => setMessagesBlock [87] => getHelper [88] => helper [89] => formatDate [90] => formatTime [91] => getModuleName [92] => __ [93] => htmlEscape [94] => stripTags [95] => urlEscape [96] => escapeUrl [97] => quoteEscape [98] => jsQuoteEscape [99] => getNameInLayout [100] => countChildren [101] => _beforeCacheUrl [102] => _afterCacheUrl [103] => getCacheKey [104] => getCacheTags [105] => addCacheTag [106] => addModelTags [107] => getCacheLifetime [108] => _loadCache [109] => _saveCache [110] => _getTagsCacheKey [111] => _getSidPlaceholder [112] => getItemsTags [113] => _isSecure [114] => _addFullNames [115] => _initOldFieldsMap [116] => _prepareSyncFieldsMap [117] => isDeleted [118] => hasDataChanges [119] => setIdFieldName [120] => getIdFieldName [121] => getId [122] => setId [123] => addData [124] => setData [125] => unsetData [126] => unsetOldData [127] => getData [128] => _getData [129] => setDataUsingMethod [130] => getDataUsingMethod [131] => getDataSetDefault [132] => hasData [133] => __toArray [134] => toArray [135] => _prepareArray [136] => __toXml [137] => toXml [138] => __toJson [139] => toJson [140] => toString [141] => __call [142] => __get [143] => __set [144] => isEmpty [145] => _underscore [146] => _camelize [147] => serialize [148] => getOrigData [149] => setOrigData [150] => dataHasChangedFor [151] => setDataChanges [152] => debug [153] => offsetSet [154] => offsetExists [155] => offsetUnset [156] => offsetGet [157] => isDirty [158] => flagDirty )
>
> COUNT:0

How am i supposed to access the block function in magento?

Am i accessing in the right way?

Comment: add your config.xml file code here

Comment: Have updated the question with the modules config xml

Comment: Can it be done anyway using my module's layout xml? where the name of the reference block is wordpress_post_list and i tried by getChildHtml()... i still get empty

Comment: paste the content of your wordpress.xml

Comment: Updated the wordpress.xml

Comment: how you are calling this phtml file in xml template\wordpress\common.phtml? there  we need to set properly.

Comment: i just placed this html in my theme folder, copying from base folder...so any changes done in this file are reflecting...

Comment: You need to investigate into the method `_getPostCollection()` to find the real reason for this.. or atleat attach that method in your question

Comment: Have updated the question with _getPostCollection() ...it returns correct in list.phtml,also i tried to give direct  $searchcountobj->_getPostCollection()..still no effect

Comment: Any clues @RajeevKTomy

Comment: From where you are calling common.phtml? Can you update the code for calling common.phtml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create object in **common.phtml** :

> app\design\frontend\rau\default\template\wordpress\common.phtml

```
 $obj = new Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List();

 $searchcount = $obj->getPosts();

 echo count($searchcount);
```

Try this.

Comment: Have updated my question using object of List class @Indranil, i still get 0 as count...!

Comment: Can you please mention the class name ? which you have seen after echo get_class($this); in list.phtml

Comment: On echo($this) in list.phtml i get Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List as class name and also updated the output for $searchcountobj, i dont think i am getting the getPosts() in ouput..whats wrong in the code?

Comment: Anyway u can correct me @IndranilMaity?

Comment: $searchcountobj = new Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_List();  After this code. Try this  print_r(get_class_methods($searchcountobj));  and paste your response here. Please.

Comment: Have posted the class methods, i can see my desired method, but why count says 0?

Comment: Any other means i can access this count value via JS or somewhere..i just need the count of posts in common.phtml

Comment: How many posts have you posted in admin ? and what about the status of these post ?

Comment: hi @Indranil, Im not sure which admin posts u referring to.. my posts are related to wordpress article posts, and im trying to get the count of these

Answer (score 0):

use below code in your phtml file

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('wordpress/post_list')->getPosts()
```

Comment: Yes i had tried that too in my custom.phtml, count says 0

Comment: Any other alternate that yu can think of suggesting for this? @Prashant

Comment: you can directly call post collection in template this one you should try

Comment: u mean to say $searchcountobj->_getPostCollection()? I tried even that..i get 0 as count

Comment: Mage::getModel using this

Comment: In the app\design\frontend\base\default\template\wordpress\search\result.phtml, they are just setting the template like :  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('wordpress/common.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

This is what your `_postCollection()` method.

```
protected function _getPostCollection()
{
$artical_type = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('article_type');
    if (is_null($this->_postCollection) && $this->getWrapperBlock()) {
        $this->_postCollection = $this->getWrapperBlock()->getPostCollection();

        if ($this->_postCollection) {
            if ($this->getPostType()) {
                $this->_postCollection->addPostTypeFilter($this->getPostType());
                if(!empty($artical_type)) {
                    $posttypevalue = Mage::helper('wordpress')->getPostMetaData();
                    if(!empty($posttypevalue)) {
                        $this->_postCollection = $this->_postCollection->addFieldToFilter('ID',array('in' => $posttypevalue));
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($this->getPagerBlock()) {
                $this->getPagerBlock()->setCollection($this->_postCollection);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->_postCollection;
}
```

As you can see here, this collections depends on two things.

1. Wrapper block
2. The parameter `article_type`.

Here the villain in your case would be most probably the wrapper block. So let's focus on that first

```
if (is_null($this->_postCollection) && $this->getWrapperBlock()) {
  //loading collection from the wrapper block
}
```

From the above condition check, it is obvious that it looks for a wrapper block in order to load the collection. When you call this block directly, this wrapper block instance may be missing or if it does really exist, then something makes the `$this->getWrapperBlock()->getPostCollection()` null again.

To debug this, now you need to find what is that wrapper block class and find it's collection method and debug there.

This is just an idea of how to find the real cause. I think this will help you to find the real culprit in your case. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Rajeev, i tried removing the getWrapperBlock() condition, seems the wrapper block is present even in the core List Block class, but not sure, even though object of that class is created, count becomes 0

Comment: Have updated the question with setwrapperblock code

Comment: @user7115281 Above I have given you an idea of how to find the real cause. Debug part you should do from your side. The purpose of the site is not give a "copy-paste and then bingo it works!!" answer, rather give you an idea on what happens in the background so that with the given info you can resolve the issue. Otherwise no one going to benefit from this forum.

Comment: Yes i understand @Rajeev, i appreciate your suggestion. im debugging from my end..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('wordpress/post_list')
    ->setTemplate('wordpress/common.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Now you can call the functions of your block class in **common.phtml**

Comment: where should i add this code? in common or list phtml? Could you please provide a detail answer

Comment: Where did you call common.phtml?

Comment: as already mentioned, i just copied the common html from base folder to my theme folder and doing changes there

Comment: But there is not such file on  base by default. Can you check the layout file if any common.phtml is called or not?

Comment: On which page you are showing common.phtml?

Comment: common phtml is a part which contains common menus and sidebars etc which are common in all pages and it appears in homepage

Comment: But that file is calling from somewhere right?